# How do I properly manipulate vector data for the Gradient Texture node in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a randomized cluster of objects with greater density near the center using a mask like this:

[image]

Here's kinda what I thought would work, though it clearly doesn't (the Color Ramp sliders don't seem to affect the mask for reasons I also don't understand):

[image]

This seems like such a simple task. I could have achieved my goals in just a few minutes if I had just modeled it like I planned. Instead, I've been troubleshooting how to do this in geo nodes for over 3 hours and I feel so stupid... I don't want to give up because the whole point was to improve my understanding of the geo nodes workflow.

I'd really appreciate any help and explanation. Thanks in advance <3

Comment: You need enough geometry for it to work. The density is sampled linearly along the edges or the faces between two vertices. Try subdividing your plane beforehand.

Comment: @Gorgious to the rescue again. This was it. I discovered the solution late last night on another forum post, but was too lazy to update my post. I'll probably delete this post since it doesn't really add anything new to the boards and the issue wasn't actually with the gradient texture in any way. I just forgot that you needed more faces (which I still don't really understand why).

Comment: A texture shader is sampled (computed) for every single pixel on your screen, whereas a geometry node is sampled for every relevant data domain (point, edge, face, etc.). In general there is far less geometry than pixels on the screen, hence the difference between the two systems. They share the same nodes but they are evaluated differently

Answer (score 0):

[image]

At first, I didn't really understand the logic either, but if we proceed from the understanding that geometric nodes are calculated and take information from the nodes that enter it (it's difficult for ordinary people who don't know how to program it), then it becomes clear that you need to take information about the current position from somewhere and somehow transform it, actually the solution it turned out very minimalistic and beautiful

Comment: The answer ended up being that my mesh needed denser geometry. That's all it was.